# Any Limitations with MatLab student version for image processing

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Are there any limitations with the MatLab student version vs the professional one when working specifically with the image processing tool box, but also in general? I have look around [here](http://www.mathworks.com/products/?s_tid=gn_ps) and Googled around and can't find a straight answer. Has anyone tried it for image processing and or "big data" processing?

THANKS

Comment: why not switch to python, numpy and scipy instead of matlab? :-)

Comment: Can scipy be used for image processing? if so, then i think you have a strong argument. I see it has other mathematical applications and data visualization capabilities.

Comment: yup, http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/ndimage.html

Comment: @FredrikPihl, python and its associated packages offer a lot of functionality for image-related processed, but there's no reason not to consider matlab equally viable. The question was about the student version, not about alternatives to matlab!

Comment: Does anyone have thoughts on the pros and cons of using PHP for image processing? http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.utilspec.image.php It appears to be feasible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The MATLAB in Student Version provides all the features and capabilities of the professional version of MATLAB software, with no limitations. There are a few small differences between the Student Version interface and the professional version of MATLAB:

The MATLAB prompt in Student Version is EDU>>
Printouts contain this footer: Student Version of MATLAB

Comment: And I used the student version myself for Image processing, nope, no difference in my opinion. But while MatLab image processing tools are good, you might want to consider learning other alternatives if you are planning to do image processing long term though. MatLab is super expensive and the cost may be your stumbling block after you graduate.

Comment: Thanks @rockinfresh. While i agree that it is costly, it seems to be industry standard here in the US for Data Science related work as it supposedly has capabilities for developing machine learning algorithms. But your point is appreciated and noted.

Comment: The answer is taken from here: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/academia/student_version/details.html. If you use Simulink, models are limited to 1,000 blocks, you can't use the accelerator modes and can use referenced models in normal mode only.